# FreeTDS translating MS SQL money type to python float, not Decimal

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

I am connecting to an MS SQL Server db from Python in Linux.  I am connecting via pyodbc using the FreeTDS driver.  When I return a money field from MSSQL it comes through as a float, rather than a Python Decimal.

The problem is with FreeTDS.  If I run the exact same Python code from Windows (where I do not need to use FreeTDS), pyodbc returns a Python Decimal.

How can I get back a Python Decimal when I'm running the code in Linux?

Comment: Are you using unixODBC?  I wonder if the problem could lie there, I'm pretty sure FreeTDS supports the decimal/money type.

Comment: I might be.  I'm heading home for the weekend now, I'll check into this on Monday.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: OK, I'm using unixODBC.  I think the problem may have been in my freetds.conf file.  I just changed the tds version from 4.2 to 8.0, but I don't know what I need to do to make the change take effect.  Do I need to restart apache? Restart something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in FreeTDS.  The bug has been fixed in the CVS head of FreeTDS as of August 4, 2010 (thanks Freddy Ziglio).  See [my post](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/msg/c796f22210ad5e59) on the web2py message board for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just convert it to Decimal when it comes back...

Comment: That ends up being a lot of conversions and isn't exactly DRY.  I agree that is the fall-back plan, but I'd really like to avoid that.